# Selecting from same table, excluding one select

Tags: sql

My table is: `nobelpeace(year, sub, win)`
I need: In which years was the English prize awarded but no Physics prize. I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT year
FROM nobelpeace
WHERE sub='english' NOT IN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT year
   FROM nobelpeace
   WHERE sub='physics')
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: All answers with "Chemistry" as one of subjects make me suspect the edit made to this question :-|

Comment: I can assure you I haven't changed the subjects! Looking at the revision history, it was changed by user3623932 himself in the edit before mine.

Comment: @user3623932 One doubt.. what values does "win" column hold?

Answer (score 1):

Your query will work, if you tell SQLServer what value should not be in the result of the subquery.

```
SELECT DISTINCT yr
FROM   nobel
WHERE  subject = 'physics'
  AND  yr NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT yr
                  FROM nobel
                  WHERE subject='chemistry')
```

Comment: @AjVJsy the subject were changed by the OP in the fifth edit, only he knows why

Answer (score 0):

Group by the year and sum how many times these prizes were awarded.

```
SELECT  yr
FROM nobel
group by yr
having sum(case when subject='physics' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
and sum(case when subject='chemistry' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

The above query works in all SQL engines. If you use MySQL you can do it even a little shorter  like this

```
SELECT  yr
FROM nobel
group by yr
having sum(subject='physics') > 0
and sum(subject='chemistry') = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT yr
FROM nobel N1
WHERE subject = 'physics'
  AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM nobel N2
    WHERE N1.yr = N2.yr
      AND N2.sublect = 'chemistry'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT yr
FROM nobel
WHERE subject = 'physics'
EXCEPT
SELECT yr
FROM nobel
WHERE subject = 'chemistry'
```

EXCEPT will do DISTINCT for you.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Way

```
select DISTINCT year from nobel
WHERE
subject='Physics'AND year
NOT IN
( select year from nobel
WHERE
subject = 'Chemistry')
```

**Demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ab2f/15